# Where does Visual Studio 2013 sql schema compare tool get its view definition from

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013

So  I was trying to compare the view definition I got from this location...

```
    Select smv.definition as VIEW_DEFINITION, v.name AS TABLE_NAME, 
    iv.IS_UPDATABLE FROM sys.all_views AS v JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smv ON
    smv.object_id = v.object_id Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views as iv 
    On iv.TABLE_NAME = v.name where v.name = @name
```

Also compared against the value at this location

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views where TABLE_NAME = @name
```

Now just for clarity I used to grab from the second location but it turns out it truncates the definition at 4000 characters while the first query does not truncate the definition..

But here is the things  both of those definitions (assuming the are short enough to not truncate)  match.  But when I go into the sql schema compare tool the view definition that shows in that tool does NOT match the view definition stored in either of those locations.

Give an example.

Lets say the view is simple   dbo.view_test

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.view_test
AS
SELECT db.dbo.tbl_view_test.col1, db.dbo.tbl_view_test.col1
FROM dbo.tbl_view_test
GO
```

So lets say THAT'S whats showing up in the sql comparison output from visual studio 2013 all seems normal...but when I go and pull the definition from either of the above queries it looks like this.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_test
AS
SELECT db.dbo.tbl_view_test.col1, db.dbo.tbl_view_test.col1
FROM dbo.tbl_view_test
GO
```

So somewhere along the way the view definition got out of whack with the view...its not supposed to be vw_test  its supposed to be view_test.

SO I guess what I'm wondering is where does the schema compare tool pull its view definition from that is different than what I am returning...and why/how could the get out of sync for the view.  Because they aren't the same.. the view in the database is named view_test  so how did its definition get modified to something else (vw_test)  and the two queries above show that difference but where ever the sql compare tool in visual studio looks it grabs the correct definition.

As you can see in the attached image.  running the two queries above both pointed at the view in question from the same database shows that the name of the view is not the same as the name for the view in its view definition.

[image]

But when I use VS2013 schema compare pointed at teh same database the view definition is correct anf the Create View is

[image]

So what I find myself wondering..is where is VS pulling that view definition from that it differs from the one I return when I query sql myself..

Update:: have now tried all of the following sql scripts all pulled from stack overflow answers as to where to pull the view definition

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views where TABLE_NAME =
'view_disc_join_cc_info_component'
Go
Select smv.definition as VIEW_DEFINITION, v.name AS TABLE_NAME,
iv.IS_UPDATABLE FROM sys.all_views AS v JOIN sys.sql_modules 
AS smv ON smv.object_id = v.object_id Join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views 
as iv On iv.TABLE_NAME = v.name where v.name =  
'view_disc_join_cc_info_component'

GO
SELECT definition, uses_ansi_nulls, uses_quoted_identifier, is_schema_bound
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.view_disc_join_cc_info_component'); 
GO
select name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) from sys.objects where type = 'V' 
and name = 'view_disc_join_cc_info_component'
GO
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID('dbo.view_disc_join_cc_info_component')) 
AS ObjectDefinition; 
GO

select c.text from sysobjects o join syscomments c on c.id = o.id where 
o.name = 'view_disc_join_cc_info_component' and o.type      = 'V'
Go
```

None of the above scripts show the view defintion Create Claus as matching the view name as it should....I only see that in the Microsoft compare tool.

Comment: I've never ever heard of any tool or bug changing an object's name... I'd assume that while doing your tests, you introduced both variants, or - what is a very often reason for such things! - you are not connected to the database you think you are connected to.

Comment: No I am certain that it is the same database.   And the data is definitely screwy. I mean when I look at the view definition from either of those queries listed above. The definitions "Create View" viewname does not match the name of the view as its displayed in  the Management Studio view list.  attached image to original post displaying the table name and view definition Create View clause to show how they are different in the database.

Comment: Could be a caching issue but I am unsure.

I would comment: clear the cache and check the object definition in sys.objects (select name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) from sys.objects where type = 'V' and name = @NameGoesHere
) matches what you expect.

Comment: cache has been cleared... I've tried a number of queries..yours included..still shows that discrepancy between the definition and the view name..unless I look at the schema in teh vs schema compare tools..then it matches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the result of an sp_rename that someone ran on your server. In the example below, after the call to sp_rename, the name of the object will be changed to vw_1 in sys.objects and object explorer, but the definition from syscomments and sys.sql_modules will still show View_1. Now if you right click on the object in object explorer and script a modify, management studio will do a find/replace and fix the problem in the generated alter script, which is what it sounds like the schema compare is doing for you.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[View_1]
AS
SELECT        dbo.Table_1.*
FROM            dbo.Table_1;

select *
from
sys.objects
where
name like 'V%'

select *
from
syscomments where text like '%View%';

select *
from
sys.sql_modules
where
[definition] like '%View%';

sp_rename 'View_1', 'vw_1';
```

Comment: K so whether I view the select * from syscomments or sys.sql_modules the view still shows the old vw...so are you saying that the compare too is automatically correcting this to match the view name on its own?  Anywhere I go to see the view definition it shows the old definition...so Im thinking based on what you are saying that the compare tool is correcting this on its own so as to have the target have the correct view definition rather than the fault old one...?

Comment: Correct. I haven't necessarily proven this with database compare before, but a while back I was working on some code to parse object definitions and I was able to prove that management studio was parsing the object definitions and doing a find/replace on the name, because I was able to get it to parse incorrectly with a very odd edge case, so I'm making an assumption that database compare is doing the same.